# Tomcat 6.0 WAR publishing problem

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I am trying to deploy WAR (20 mb in size) to Tomcat 6.0 server. I selected a war file, clicked deploy button, it would take few seconds and on the top it would show message OK, but app wouldn't show up on the list of applications.

In the webapps folder, on the server, there is no WAR file. It should be.

Before this started happening, I remember it would take rally long time to stop any app, then it would take long time to deploy an WAR. I think one of those times I lost patience and I tried to refresh the page.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Tomcat logs mention anything?

Answer (score 2):

**I have a few suggestions.**

1. First it may be you are deploying on a different tomcat server in different
   location. Try deploying it, get "OK" message and then again deploy
   it, it should say "Application already exists at path /yourApp". If
   it does, then the point is proven.
2. Second try putting your .war into webapps
   directory, it should automatically unzip it and deploy, if not -
   unrar .war file and add contents instead.

In both situations manually check your path in browser (localhost:8080/app or smth).
Also check for tomcat logs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The interesting thing is, I came in this morning, logged it to server/manager and my app was listed. Checked all services, and services are working too. Don't know what happened. But thank you anyway. Next time I will pay attention to log files.